# Integral $I=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\big(\sqrt{x^2 + 2}\big)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}(x^2 + 1)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hi I'm trying to show that 
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\big(\sqrt{x^2 + 2}\big)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}(x^2 + 1)}dx=\frac{5\pi^2}{96}.
$$
We can try the substitution $u=(x^2+2)^{1/2}, du=x(2+x^2)^{-1/2}dx$ but that didn't help me much because of the (x^2+1) piece.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @RandomVariable Nice.  Thank you again

Comment: See also the book "Inside Interesting Integrals..."